# GNU Mailman stuck in loop sending to itself

Tags: postfix, mailman, raspbian

When I send an email to my Mailman mailing list address, it is getting stuck in a loop.  When I send an email out, the email that is supposed to get sent to the list of subscribed people, instead it sends the email to the mailing list address, causing an infinite loop of sending the email to itself.  The problem seems to have appeared for no reason (the list used to work just fine).  What should I do?

Raspbian Stretch
Mailman 1:2.1.23-1
Postfix 3.1.0-5+b1

`/etc/aliases`: http://paste.debian.net/870363/
`/etc/mailman/mm_cfg.py`: http://paste.debian.net/870364/
`/etc/postfix/main.cf`: http://paste.debian.net/883021/
`/etc/postfix/master.cf`: http://paste.debian.net/883038/
`end of /var/log/mail.warn`: http://paste.debian.net/884140/
`/var/log/mail.err` is empty

EDIT: Does not seem to be an issue with Postfix, [my website's contact form](https://jacobspctuneup.tk/contactform.php) works just fine.

Comment: Please show the relevant configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Config added, logs coming soon.

Comment: @masegaloeh Config added, logs coming soon.

Comment: Those two logs aren't relevant in this looping case. Can you post the content of mail.info or wherever postfix log WHEN looping happen?

Comment: Apart from the above, could you please show the output of `/usr/local/mailman/bin/config_list -o - <your-list-name>`

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider:

1. the Mailman address should not be a part of your mailing list.
2. you should take care for Automatic replays such as: Out of office or Similar feedbacks.

Comment: These are not the issue, even the mailman@blahblahblah "list" has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that happend because you configure relayhost postfix main.cf

This is the warning in your log

```
Oct 19 17:34:00 jacobspctuneup postfix/trivial-rewrite[2762]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 41: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=
```

You can comment or delete it

Or you can give some log, so I can get other information to find the error

Comment: The first one was just `relayhost = `, so I don't think it is the issue, but removed it anyway.

Comment: Awarded the bounty to this answer, although it was not my problem, that error had been annoying me for a while, and the answer motivated me to finally fix it.